# Are these two sources coherent?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

If I connect 2 solenoids to an AC source in parallel, they would emit electromagnetic waves. Would the 2 solenoid sources of waves be coherent? Would they be considered as the same source?

Also, what would be the answer if I connected the solenoids in series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you sort of meant antennas when you were referring to "solenoids" on a source. (Perfect solenoids, I believe, should not have any leakage, although in reality there is always some leaking fields on the edges.)

Anyways, yes. Radiations from two antennas driven by a single source, whether they are connected in series or in parallel, would be coherent. Keep in mind that "coherence" means that two wave sources maintain a constant phase relationship.